# Use Where In clause with Table-Valued User-Defined Function in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table-Valued User-Defined Functions named "GetRelatedUsersIds", which in turn return all sub users (including itself) for any particular user if any.

And I have a scenario where I want this function to be used in where in clause as given below:-

```
Create procedure [ABC]
(
@AddedBy Int,
@LoggedUser int=0
)
as
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
where AddedBy in (case when @AddedBy =0 then (select UserId from dbo.GetRelatedUsersIds(@LoggedUser)) else @AddedBy end)
```

Here I looking for variable @AddedBy if its 0 then I will go for variable @LoggedUser.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[GetRelatedUsersIds]
(
@ccManagerId INT
) 
returns @tableUsersId table(UserId int)
AS
.... code
```

But as UDF returns a table so I am getting an error of "Subquery returned more than 1 value".

How to solve this issue, TIA.

Comment: That isn't how a case expression works. It is designed to return a single value, not control logic like you are trying to do here.

Comment: I know but can I use this udf in where in clause any how..

Comment: Well if the function returns more than 1 row you are going to get this error because the subquery returned more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need something like this. But don't use select *. Instead you need to be explicit and use the column names you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
where AddedBy in 
(
    select UserId 
    from dbo.GetRelatedUsersIds(@LoggedUser) 
    where @AddedBy = 0
)
OR 
(
    @AddedBy <> 0
    AND
    AddedBy = @AddedBy
)
```